# Maven dependency doesn't exist after pom.xml dependency addition in Java?

Tags: java, maven, miglayout

After I added this dependency to my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
  <artifactId>miglayout-swing</artifactId>
  <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to `import com.miglayout.*;` but I got the error:

> package `com.miglayout` does not exist

How come nothing is wrong with other libraries I have imported using Maven in the same project, but I get issues with `com.miglayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct package is `net.miginfocom.*`

The maven groupId does not always correlate with the package name.

See MigLayout [Javadocs](http://www.miglayout.com/mavensite/apidocs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The classes inside the MiG layout library are under the packages:

- [`net.miginfocom.swing`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.0/) for the `miglayout-swing` artefact
- [`net.miginfocom.layout`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.miglayout/miglayout-core/5.0) for the `miglayout-core` artefact (transitive dependency of `miglayout-swing`).

If you are using an IDE, you should not write the imports yourself and let the IDE handle it. This way, you will avoid mistakes relating to wrong package imports. Also, you should not use import on-demand and prefer single type import.